# how to convert avi file to an jpg's images array using .net

Tags: c#, .net, video, image

how to convert avi file to an jpg's images array using .net , i need to develop a task that will take the avi file and save it as jpg images on another folder

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this from the command line with [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org).  See [this part](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html#SEC5) of the documentation.  For example,

```
ffmpeg -i infile.avi -f image2 image-%03d.jpg
```

will save all frames from `infile.avi` as numbered jpegs (image-001.jpg, image-002.jpg,...).  You can then use other command line options to get just the frames you want or do some other post processing like resizing or deinterlacing.

You could just create a program in .NET that calls the ffmpeg executable with the right command line and moves the resulting files into the correct place.  It would be much easier than trying to use some video library directly.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at: http://ffmpegdotnet.codeplex.com/

Looking a bit further, it appears there is no download there, but found this too:

http://www.intuitive.sk/fflib/post/fflib-net-released.aspx

Answer (score 0):

.NET has no out-of-the-box way of managing audio or video. You'd have to use an external API.
DirectX for example can handle .avi files.