# ffmpeg split avi into frames with known frame rate

Tags: linux, image-processing, ffmpeg

I posted this as comments under [this related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002601/converting-avi-frames-to-jpgs-on-linux). However, they seem to have gone unnoticed =(

I've used

```
ffmpeg -i myfile.avi -f image2 image-%05d.bmp
```

to split `myfile.avi` into frames stored as `.bmp` files. It seemed to work except not quite. When recording my video, I recorded at a rate of `1000fps` and the video turned out to be `2min29sec` long. If my math is correct, that should amount to a total of **149,000 frames** for the entire video. However, when I ran

```
ffmpeg -i myfile.avi -f image2 image-%05d.bmp
```

I only obtained 4472 files. How can I get the original 149k frames?

I also tried to convert the frame rate of my original AVI to 1000fps by doing

```
ffmpeg -i myfile.avi -r 1000 otherfile.avi
```

but this didn't seem to fix my concern.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -i myfile.avi -r 1000 -f image2 image-%07d.png
```

I am not sure outputting 150k bmp files will be a good idea. Perhaps png is good enough?

Comment: this worked for my video i recorded off my pen camera

Comment: Using `-r 1000` will force ffmpeg to simply duplicate (or drop frames if input fps is higher) the frames to reach 1000. Probably not what you want.

Answer (score 12):

Part one of your math is good, the 2 minutes and 29 seconds is about 149 seconds. With 1000 fps that makes 149000 frames. However your output filename only has 5 positions for the number where 149000 has 6 positions, so try "image-%06d.bmp".

Then there is the disk size: Do your images fit on the disk? With bmp every image uses its own size. You might try to use jpeg pictures, they compress about 10 times better.

Another idea: If ffmpeg does not find a (reasonable) frame rate, it drops to 25 or 30 frames per second. You might need to specify it. Do so for both source and target, see the man page (`man ffmpeg` on unix):

```
   To force the frame rate of the input file (valid for raw formats
   only) to 1 fps and the frame rate of the output file to 24 fps:
           ffmpeg -r 1 -i input.m2v -r 24 output.avi
```

For what it's worth: I use `ffmpeg -y -i "video.mpg" -sameq "video.%04d.jpg"` to split my video to pictures. The -sameq is to force the jpeg in a reasonable quality, the -y is to avoid allow overwrite questions. For you:

ffmpeg -y -r 1000 -i "myfile.avi" -sameq "image.%06d.jpg"

Comment: -sameq is now deprecated

Answer (score 0):

I think, there is a misconception here: the output of a HS video system is unlikely to have an output frame rate of 1000 fps but something rather normal as 30 (or 50/60) fps. Apart from overloading most video players with this kind of speed it would be counterproductive to show the sequence in the same speed as it was recorded. 
Basically: 1 sec @ 1000 fps input is something like 33 sec @ 30 fps output.

Was the duration of the scene recorded really 2:29 min (resulting in a video ~82 min at normal rate) or took it about 4.5 sec (4472 frames) which is 2:29 min in normal playback?

Answer (score 0):

**I tried this on ubuntu 18.04 terminal.**

```
ffmpeg -i input_video.avi output_frame_path_images%5d.png
```

where,

-i = Input

Answer (score 0):

**With FFMPEG I was only getting around 33k files but if you use Python you can use this code and it created the proper 41k files for a 23min video at 29.97FPS.**

```python
import cv2
import os
import sys

###------------------------------------------------------------------------ ###
    
def vid_split():
    
    print("Splitting videos to images(.jpg) at the videos frames per second.",
          "\n", "For example at 30 FPS, you'll get 30 images for every second of video.", "\n")
    
    videoFile = "./Path/To/Video.mp4"
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(videoFile)
    frameRate = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
    pic_num = 0
    framenum = 0
    maxframe = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))

    while(cap.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret == False:
            break
        framenum += 1

        print(f"\rProcessing: {framenum} of {maxframe}",end="")
        sys.stdout.flush()

        # zfill puts the number of zeros before framenum, if framenum is 1
        # filename would be frame00000001.jpg
        filename = "tmp_frames/frame{}.jpg".format(str(framenum).zfill(8))

        if os.path.exists(filename):
            pass
        else:
            cv2.imwrite(str(filename), frame)
        pic_num += 1

    print(f"\r                                                                                          ",end="")

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    print("[*] Completed Video Operations! ", "\n")
    
vid_split()
```