# How to read an AVI file in OpenCV for Android

Tags: android, opencv

I need to read an AVI file in Android and process its frames. I know its C++ way but not the android one! Can someone help me and give a start point. I'm using opencv 2.4.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to compile OpenCV with FFMPEG for Android.

Video IO is not officially supported but if I remember correctly this patch worked: http://code.opencv.org/issues/2546 At least you can use it as a good starting point.

Comment: Do you know any tutorials about compiling OpenCV with FFMPEG for Android?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jayrambhia/4ede34930c9a067ea3f8 <- it could be useful. It is the necessary configuration to compile the FFMPEG

Comment: It seems you have to download ffmpeg source code and put in the correct folder in order to include correct dependencies for Android (ARM arquitecture)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [javacv](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/), it has ffmpeg and opencv wrappers with examples.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it is implemented yet (at least it wasn't [six months ago](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-opencv/ZFLjcaWWvBg)). You might want to split you video into frames and open those frames instead of the video file (have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917601/ffmpeg-split-avi-into-frames-with-known-frame-rate)).

Comment: but my video is really big and I can't split its frames to images.

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure if it's useful , but take a look at this:

http://www.stanford.edu/class/ee368/Android/Tutorial-2-OpenCV-for-Android-Setup-Macintosh-API11.pdf