# How to extract a frame from video using Java

Tags: java, video-processing

Is there any solution to "Extract a frame from video file in Java using core library without importing external libraries"?

Say for I saw `Image`, `BufferedStrategy`, `BufferCapabilities` in Java AWT libraries.

Answer (score 1):

The **Java Media Framework** API (**JMF**) enables audio, video and other time-based media operations, without use of any third party library.

[Seeking frames inside a movie with JMF](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/seek-176881.html).

[**xuggler**](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/index) is a good third party library, widely used.

Comment: FYI, JMF is dead long ago. Xuggler is a massive load of work.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use Xuggler [from here](http://www.xuggle.com/) or you can find it [in maven](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|xuggle).

In the github repository is [a sample](https://github.com/artclarke/xuggle-xuggler/tree/master/src/com/xuggle/xuggler/demos) under demos with the file:
`DecodeAndCaptureFrames.java`

Comment: the OP asks for `without importing external libraries "`

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35006670/1893325) on another question, you can do that without external libraries by leveraging features of JavaFX.

Quoting original answer below:

> You can use the snapshot() of MediaView. First connect a mediaPlayer
>   to a MediaView component, then use mediaPlayer.seek() to seek the
>   video position. And then you can use the following code to extract the
>   image frame:

```
int width = mediaPlayer.getMedia().getWidth();
int height = mediaPlayer.getMedia().getHeight();
WritableImage wim = new WritableImage(width, height);
MediaView mv = new MediaView();
mv.setFitWidth(width);
mv.setFitHeight(height);
mv.setMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer);
mv.snapshot(null, wim);
try {
    ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(wim, null), "png", new File("/test.png"));
} catch (Exception s) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```